# Django Rest API Post call

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to check the username and password is existed in  mysql DB table and provide result ("existed" or "Notexisted"). Please provide the full solution to this as i am a beginner in Django.

I already connected to the mysqldb . but i don't know how the structure should

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through this article before asking questions in SO, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Apart from that, you could use Django's [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) method